# pyomo - How do I run multiple solve() concurrently/in parallel on the same model?

Tags: python, concurrency, pool, pyomo, glpk

I'm using `opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')`, and I'd like to call `opt.solve()`, multiple times, inside a map function of a ThreadPool, but it gives error caused by race conditions.

It doesn't work even if I instanciate opt inside the map function.

The errors I get are random, but in many cases they refer to a log_file which can't be opened.

I'm even cloning the model for each map function call, to avoid race conditions on it.

I can't use MPI, I need to use a ThreadPool (which parallelizes only I/O ops, like waiting for the solver to end the task, which is good enough for me)

**Edit**

Opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/2475

Answer (score 1):

The GLPK manual for Version 4* says that GLPK is not thread-safe.  So regardless of what you do in python, the solver isn't going to cooperate.

*version 5 is out for GLPK, but I cannot find a reference manual for it.  I think it is safe to assume that it is still not thread safe or such news would turn up with a web search.

Comment: Are you saying that calling glpsol more than once at the same time isn't safe? 

Comment: That’s my understanding…. But I don’t have definitive proof, nor do I attempt to run parallel calls to it.  Search references are a bit sketchy, but I think that is the conclusion…. There are internal constructs in glpk that cannot be shared amongst threads.  Perhaps somebody with more detailed knowledge of glpk will jump in and confirm or refute!